Using TabController in ModalRoute
I need to know a way to use TabView in ModalRoute. I want to use custom controller instead of a DefaultTabController. How can I do it?
I have tried using DefaultTabController but I need to have access to the TabController itself. Here is my current code I have tried. The ticker mixin will not work for ModalRoute so I have no idea how to solve
class TransferScreen extends ModalRoute<void> {
  final _controller = Get.put(TransferController(maxPage: 4));

  @override
  Duration get transitionDuration => const Duration(milliseconds: 500);

  @override
  bool get opaque => false;

  @override
  bool get barrierDismissible => false;

  @override
  Color? get barrierColor => Colors.white;

  @override
  String? get barrierLabel => null;

  @override
  bool get maintainState => false;

  @override
  Widget buildPage(
    BuildContext context,
    Animation<double> animation,
    Animation<double> secondaryAnimation,
  ) {
        DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            appBar: PreferredSize(
              preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(34 + 15),
              child: TabBar(
                isScrollable: true,
                indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
                indicatorWeight: 4,
                indicatorColor: Color(0xFFF0B919),
                labelColor: Color(0xFFF0B919),
                labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium?.copyWith(
                      color: Color(0xFFB3B3B3),
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                      fontSize: 14,
                    ),
                unselectedLabelColor: Color(0xFFB3B3B3),
                unselectedLabelStyle:
                    Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium?.copyWith(
                          color: Color(0xFFB3B3B3),
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.w400,
                          fontSize: 14,
                        ),
                dividerHeight: 0,
                tabAlignment: TabAlignment.start,
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 15,
                  left: 16,
                  right: 16,
                ),
                tabs: [
                  '1. Enquiry Quote',
                  '2. Select Recipient',
                ]
                    .map(
                      (tab) => Container(
                        width: 180,
                        height: 34,
                        alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                        child: Text(tab),
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList(),
              ),
            ),
            body: TabBarView(
              children: [
                _buildEnquiryQuote(context),
                _buildSelectRecipient(context),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        )
  }
}


I never use ModalRoute but got an idea. Can you store TabController in controller and use through controller.tabController like this in TabView
